# Extract String from DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to extract a string from a column of XML data (string) within my pyspark dataframe. I am looking to extract the value of the ProductName for each customer.

Below is an example of the data:

```
 Customer, Product
 A, <XmlData ProductName="123">....</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="1452">....</XmlData>
 B, <XmlData ProductName="123">....</XmlData>
 C, <XmlData ProductName="123">....</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="1452">....</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="893">....</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="3453">....</XmlData>
```

I would like to transform my dataframe to include a column which has a list of the extracted ProductNames like below:

```
 Customer, ProductName
 A, 123;1452
 B, 123
 C, 123;1452;893;3453
```

Comment: Use this lib from databricks - https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Answer (score 0):

If your XML structure is static, just replace the surrounding XML strings with ";" 
(use [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#replace) or [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#regexp_replace)), leaving the values, and create a new column with the result (*withColumn* method).

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple udf

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

extract = udf(lambda s: list(map(lambda x: x.split('=')[1] if len(x)>0 else x,re.findall('(ProductName=\"\d+\")', s))), ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn('values', extract('Product')).show(30,False)

+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|Customer|             Product|              values|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       A|<XmlData ProductN...|     ["123", "1452"]|
|       B|<XmlData ProductN...|             ["123"]|
|       C|<XmlData ProductN...|["123", "1452", "...|
|       D|                    |                  []|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+

df = df.withColumn('values',f.concat_ws(';','values'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala -

```scala
  val regexp_extractAll = udf((xml: String, exp: String) =>
      exp.r.findAllMatchIn(xml).map(_.group(1)).mkString(";")
    )

    df.withColumn("ProductName", regexp_extractAll($"Product", lit("""ProductName="(\d+)"""")))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
      * |Customer|Product                                                                      |ProductName       |
      * +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
      * |A       |<XmlData ProductName="123">x</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="1452">y</XmlData>|123;1452|
      * |B       |<XmlData ProductName="123">x</XmlData>                                       |123     |
      * |C       |<XmlData ProductName="123">x</XmlData><XmlData ProductName="1452">y</XmlData>|123;1452|
      * +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
      */
```